# The 'pip==9.0.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: pip

I have the latest version of pip in my laptop.I always get this error when I install any modules using pip.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3195, in <module>
   @_call_aside
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3179, in _call_aside
   f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-p 
  packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3208, in _ 
  initialize_master_working_set
  working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 681, in _build_master
   ws.require(__requires__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
   packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 999, in require
   needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
    packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 885, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

How do I resolve this error.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely your pip crashed due to missing dependencies. Try reinstalling pip.

> sudo easy_install pip==9.0.3

Answer (score 3):

i was facing the same problem you had. But after 3 hour of surfing the internet, i found the solution. Use

> > > python -m pip

command to run pip.

When you want to install a new modules,

> > > python -m pip install "modules name"

This will solve your problem!!

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you @E' topia

Comment: This has worked for me too. But why does Python/Pip get itself into this state and why does this fix work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Homebrew. If so, what worked for me was running `brew reinstall python`. That brought in a clean copy of pip.